# Avoid customer email notification for a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I am trying to stop customer order email for a particular product category in woocommerce.

What I have tried is:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'wc_change_customer_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 3);
function wc_change_customer_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
 global $woocommerce;
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $category_ids = array( 10 );
    $flagHasProduct = false;
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ); 

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  
            if( in_array( $term->term_id, $category_ids ) ) {
                $flagHasProduct = true;
            }
        }

    }
    if ($flagHasProduct) {
        $recipient = "";
    } 
    $recipient = "";
    return $recipient;
}
```

But this hook is not working at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this instead *(with `has_term()` WP conditional function)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order', 'product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification', 10, 2 );
function product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification( $recipient, $order ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $recipient;

    // HERE set your product categories (coma separated term Ids, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array( 10 );

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = $item->get_product(); 
        // Get the correct product ID (for variations we take the parent product ID)
        $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

        // Check for product categories for this item
        if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            return ''; // If it's found, we return an empty recipient
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.

> This will avoid **only Customer "processing" order email notification**.

**For Others customer order email notification,** you will have to add also:

```
// Customer "completed" Order email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification', 10, 2 );

// Customer "on-hold" Order email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_on_hold_order', 'product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification', 10, 2 );

// Customer "refunded" Order email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_refunded_order', 'product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification', 10, 2 );

// Customer "invoice" email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_invoice', 'product_cat_avoid_processing_email_notification', 10, 2 );
```

---

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [Wordpress has_term() function *(for custom taxonomy as a conditional tag)*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)